# C++ Windows: Access same variable from main process and CallWndProc process

Tags: c++, windows, hook

I have a single-file DLL that receives and stores a `_bstr_t` as a global variable, then sets a Windows hook for the `WH_CALLWNDPROC` procedure.

In the `CallWndProc` function, I attempt to read the `_bstr_t`, but it has no value.

I printed out the variable's address from both functions and they are different.

This is not surprising as I think that the `CallWndProc` function is called in a different process' thread.

My question is, what is the easiest and best way to share the variable between them?

I am trying to avoid having to use `ATL COM` to store it for inter-process access.

**Example code:**

```
// foo.cpp
#include <comutil.h>

static HHOOK g_hook = NULL;
static _bstr_t shared = "";

static LRESULT WINAPI CallWndProc(int nHookCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (nHookCode == 12345) {
        // Do something with '_bstr_t shared'
        shared += " bar";
        return 0;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(g_hook, nHookCode, wParam, lParam);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void _stdcall Do(char* someStr, long handle) {
    shared = someStr;

    DWORD threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId((HWND) handle, &process);
    HINSTANCE hInst = GetModuleHandle("foo.dll");
    g_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, CallWndProc, hInst, thread);

    // Check value of '_bstr_t shared', or call a COM function to store it somewhere.
    // However, the value of 'shared' does not include the string appended in CallWndProc.
}
```

Extra info:

- DLL is called by Java using JNI.
- DLL is built as a multi-threaded DLL.

Comment: There are only hard ways, a named pipe is the usual approach.

Comment: I went with the ATL COM approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the ATL COM approach to act as a global store of values.
Not my ideal solution, but a workable one.

However, I think Hans Passant's comment on the question is a better way of doing it since it does not require a separate process to be running.